# Серврер не отвечает на запрос по ip nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, веб-сервер

Запустил nginx на своем пк на ubuntu. Елси ввожу в браузере 0.0.0.0:81 получаю содержимое index.html. Если делаю это через [мой ip]:81 ответ на запрос не приходит. Подскажите, с чем это может быть связанно.

```
server {
   listen :81;
   listen [::]:81;

   allow all;

   server_name testnginx.com;

   root /var/www/testnginx.com;
   index index.html;

   location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

Comment: откуда вы взяли [мой ip] ?